# Prove using the epsilon delta definition

Tags: calculus

Prove using the Epsilon delta definition : $\lim\limits_{x\to 4}(x^2-\sqrt x)=14$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$|x^2-\sqrt{x}-14|=|x^2-14-\sqrt{x}|=\left|\frac{(x^2-14)^2+x}{x^2-14+\sqrt{x}}\right|$$

Now try to estimate the denoinator and the numerator for values of $x$ close to $4$ which is a local minumum of the denominator (e.g. $|x^2-14+\sqrt{x}|>|2+2|=4$).